# What is the simplest way to interpolate the selected params id with Angular?

Tags: angular

I have this url: .../restaurants/4

I want to display the value of the selected id. Which in the case would be the restaurant number 4.

What is the easiest way to bind the params id of restaurant?

Thanks

Comment: Yes my goal is to have this is my html `<h1>Restaurant number {{id}} </h1>`

Comment: Look at my answer below. The code returns the `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it this way.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  restaurant: Restaurant;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = (params.get('id'));
      this.restaurant = restaurant[this.id];
      });
  }
```

and used `{{ restaurant.id }}` in the html

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at sample code:

```
  this.name = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get("paramName")
  this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(queryParams => {
    this.name = queryParams.get("paramName")
  })
```

This will give you the param value. In the template use {{param}}.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that returns the `id`.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';

constructor( private router: Router) {}

this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd ) {
    const currentUrl = event.url;
    // Get all characters after the last slash in url
    const id = current.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
    // id return 4 based on your provided link
  }
});
```